# Node.js: Cannot set a value '0xff' by 'buf.writeIntBE()'

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I can write *-1* to the buffer by *writeIntBE*, the code is:

```
var b = new Buffer(1);
b.writeIntBE(-1, 0, 1);
console.log(b);
//<Buffer ff>
```

However, the following code is not functional

```
var b = new Buffer(1);
b.writeIntBE(0xff, 0, 1);
console.log(b);
```

The error code is :

```
buffer.js:794
    throw new TypeError('value is out of bounds');
    ^

TypeError: value is out of bounds
    at checkInt (buffer.js:794:11)
    at Buffer.writeIntBE (buffer.js:919:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/liuzeya/http/examples/buffer.js:2:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

Help me understanding the difference, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by examining the source at:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0a329d2d1f6bce2410d65ecd47175b5a4e1c1c91/lib/buffer.js

We can see the call to checkInt:

```
checkInt(this,
         value,
         offset,
         byteLength,
         Math.pow(2, 8 * byteLength - 1) - 1,
         -Math.pow(2, 8 * byteLength - 1));
```

Working out the Math.pow's, we see the min is -128 and the max is 127. If we evaluate `0xff` alone in the console, we see that is **positive** 255, which is out of range.

So hexadecimal constants are always positive. I'm sure you can find this in the JavaScript standard. Whereas, you're using the *signed* version of the call. You can have explicit negative hexadecimal values in JavaScript, which looks freaking odd in my opinion, but that would be `-0x1` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can I suppose it an issue, or I just need to embrace it?

Comment: An easier solution might be to `writeUIntBE`.  `0xff` or `255` is a valid value for a single byte if you're treating it as unsigned.

Comment: @AaronDufour I think `b.writeIntBE(0xff, 0, 1, true);` is better. The last parameter *true* makes no call to `checkInt`.  https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0a329d2d1f6bce2410d65ecd47175b5a4e1c1c91/lib/buffer.js#L912

Comment: -1 to that previous comment. Don't disable sanity checks. Use the API correctly as @AaronDufour suggested. It is not an issue, but well-defined behavior of JavaScript, so yes embrace it. :-)

Comment: @liuzeyafzy Why is it better to disable assertions than to call the correct method in the first place?  There's no reason to believe that will continue to work, since you're invoking undefined behavior.  For example, similar code in earlier versions of node would use `0` in any place it got out of range values.